# Visual Studio keeps running the old build and doesn't update my project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Even if I made changes and rebuilt the project, it woould not update he debugged project. Also, I have searched for possible solutions but they did not work for me.

Here are the possible solutions I've tried that did not work:

1. Configure Manager > Make sure that I haved checked the Build box
2. Delete bin and obj folders (made errors for me)